# Embedding windows in GUI

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to build an app that does 2 things.

1. Get live feed from webcam and display it using OpenCV. (tried IP Camera but gave up, its still not working)
2. Plot a chart on the basis of the video input.

The webcam feed is working, I am able to display it using `imshow()` and `namedWindow()`
.
The chart I have made using **Tkinter.**

The two outputs above, I want to add them in a single frame. Is it possible to do so?

And what do I use to embed them in a single window?

Please note I am using Python and developing on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two or more output windows into a single output window using numpy stack concept.

Referene Link:-

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack

Sample Code:-

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('Bird1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('Bird2.jpg')

img_stack = np.hstack((img1,img2))

cv2.imshow('Image Stack',img_stack)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note:-

You can combine any number of output windows into single one. To do this, 
the Input Images Height, Width and Channel must be same.

Channel means, If images are in RGB Mode means all Images should be in RGB Mode.

You cannot combine, one RGB Mode Image and one  Grayscale Mode Image into a single window.

Like Images, you may also stack videos.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am trying to do something different. I want to enclose the outputs in a single window i.e. the two should be embedded in a frame or something. Is my question unclear? Should I edit it? And do you have the answer to my question?

Comment: Okay Prakhar Mohan Srivastava, please update your question. I will try to answer your question. I have a similar doubt. Please visit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930480/adding-gui-window-to-python-opencv2-program-with-pygtk3